# Using back camera in WebRTC in Swift

Tags: swift, webrtc

To switch cameras in WebRTC I want to choose the correct camera device (back camera) and then use RTCVideoCapturer to define the video source.

In Objective C this looks like the following:

```
RTCVideoCapturer *capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraID];
RTCMediaConstraints *mediaConstraints = [self defaultMediaStreamConstraints];
RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [_factory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer constraints:mediaConstraints];
localVideoTrack = [_factory videoTrackWithID:@"ARDAMSv0" source:videoSource];
```

It seems that the only constructor for RTCVideoCapurer avaliable requires a delegate, i.e.

```
let capturer = RTCVideoCapturer(delegate: <#T##RTCVideoCapturerDelegate#>)
```

So how can I translate the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Translation In Swift 3**

```
var capturer = RTCVideoCapturer(deviceName: cameraID)
var mediaConstraints: RTCMediaConstraints? = defaultMediaStreamConstraints()
var videoSource: RTCVideoSource? = factory.videoSource(with: capturer, constraints: mediaConstraints)
localVideoTrack = factory.videoTrack(withID: "ARDAMSv0", source: videoSource)
```

There is a "bool" property called "useBackCamera" in RTCAVFoundationVideoSource class (***RTCAVFoundationVideoSource.h***). You can make use of this property to switch between front/back camera.

```
//In  RTCAVFoundationVideoSource.h

/** Returns whether rear-facing camera is available for use. */
@property(nonatomic, readonly) BOOL canUseBackCamera;

/** Switches the camera being used (either front or back). */
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL useBackCamera;

/** Returns the active capture session. */
@property(nonatomic, readonly) AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
```